# Take a result of two long numbers using an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to take a sum, quotient, remainder of two numbers using an array in java.
123456789012345+7654321, 123456789012345/7654321. What is a simplest way to calculate it using Java?(I am new to Java.)

Comment: can you show us an example,I can't understand your question well.

Comment: I don't understand the array part, but the `BigInteger` class has methods to do all these calculations.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see how far you get? As a good side effect, when you run into a problem, you have an actual concrete question you can ask here.

Comment: If I tell it simply, I want to get the result of 123456789012345+7654321 and  123456789012345/7654321 using java program.  Can you give any help for solve this.

Comment: Some code may be help to sort out your problem?

Comment: @Emalka We all want things, but when you post on this website, people expect that you have done your research. When you're talking about a coding problem, that means that you must have tried it yourself and can show where you are stuck. This is not a "write my code for me" website.

Comment: Start with a basic "Hello World" Java program, then replace the `"Hello World"` string with the calculation `123456789012345L + 7654321L`, and *Viola!* you have your result. Then copy the `println` statement, and replace `+` with `/`, and *Viola!* you have your other result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new to java I recommend reading up on some tutorials. As it seems you are not familiar with java in general. An example, which I have not used myself, is http://www.javaworld.com/blog/java-101. It may be worth your time to read this over.

As for your actual question, you would create a variable in java. Then assign your first number to this variable. After doing this, you can perform some operations on the number.

An example in sudo code to give you an idea while not doing the work for you.

```
void method
  var number = 100
  number = number + 200
  number = number / 20
  print("result" . number)
```

If you plan to use an array its the same process in a loop.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm